# Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Express $\cos^7\theta$ as a polynomial of $\cos\theta$. 
Hence show that $\sec^2\frac{\pi}{14} + \sec^2 \frac{3\pi}{14} + \sec^2 \frac{5\pi}{14} = 8$.

I'm new to complex numbers and I'm unsure about how to solve this. When the question says polynomial, does it want the answer in terms of $\cos\theta, \cos2\theta$ and so on? If so, how do I answer the second part?

Comment: I see nothing in the problem statement that mentions complex numbers. Why do you think the answer requires complex numbers?

Comment: Oh, because this is under the complex numbers chapter my teacher is teaching now.

Comment: $\cos^7\theta$ as polynomial in $\cos\theta$ is quite easy (the polymial $x\mapsto x^7$). Don't you mean $\cos(7\theta)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use complex numbers, then the first part is relatively simple:
$$
\cos(7\theta) = \operatorname{Re}(\cos(7\theta) + i\sin(7\theta)) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{7i\theta}) = \operatorname{Re}((e^{i\theta})^7) = \operatorname{Re}((\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^7)
$$
and use the binomial theorem.

When it says as a polynimial in $\cos\theta$, it means that you're allowed to use complex numbers, and $\cos\theta, \cos^2\theta, \cos^3\theta$ and so on.

For the second part, I'd try rewriting the $\sec$ to $\frac{1}{\cos}$, multiply away the denominators, use $\theta = \frac{\pi}{14}$ and see if the first part of the problem doesn't help somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit calculation for part 1: 
$$
\cos(7x) = \Re(e^{7ix}) =  \Re((\cos x  + i\sin x )^7)\\
=\Re(\cos^7 x + 7i\cos^6 x \sin x - 21\cos^5 x \sin^2 x  - 35i\cos^4 x \sin^3 x  + 35\cos^3 x \sin^4 x + 21i\cos^2 x \sin^5 x  - 7\cos x \sin^6 x - i\sin^7 x)
$$
Now use $\sin^2 x = 1 -\cos^2 x$ and get 
$$\cos(7x) = 64\cos^7 x - 112\cos^5 x + 56 \cos^3 x -7 \cos x$$
You can check this using [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)
 : We have the relation
$\cos(n x)= T_n(\cos x)$ and $T_7(x) = 64 x^7 - 112 x^5 + 56x^3-7x$